# What is calling class method on constructor?

Tags: java

I'm aware of just basic concepts of java.
Today I was learning about super keyword from here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2

And in code example found this code snippet

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new T3().test(); ---> What is happening here ?
    }
}
```

May I know what is happening with new T3().test(); ? Is it a new object ? If yest then why its not written as below ?

```
T3 ob = new T3().test();
```

Or they have written in way because return type of test() method is void. Means no reference type can be created ? Am I correct ?

Can anyone help me to understand this ? What is actually happening with this code snippet ? I just know only we use this way only when we need to create an object like this only

**Classtype vrblName = new Constructor();**

Comment: `new T3().test()` and `T3 ob = new T3().test()` do the same thing, but the latter retains a reference to newly created object.  Maybe the code you are looking at doesn't need that reference?

Comment: It is creating a new `T3` object and then calling the `test` method on that Object.  As `test` maybe does not return anything I would say that `T3 ob = new T3().test();` is incorrect.  A different way would be `T3 obj = new T3();`  and then `obj.test();`

Comment: Your second example is only possible if `T3.test()` returns a `T3`. The *equivalent* would be `{ T3 ob = new T3(); ob.test(); }`, note that `ob` leaves scope after calling `test()` and is thus eligible for garbage collection (as in your first example).

Comment: @ScaryWombat  like you said "It is creating a new T3 object" then why cant we give him class's reference variable ?

Comment: The `new` is creating the object and from that step you can assign to a variable **but** if you don't and call `test` then you are stuck with whatever `test` returns

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, May be, But could you please tell what exactly they are trying to achieve using this code snippet ? I mean what is happening actually ? Like you said object is being created but what is happening next when we are calling test method along with constructor ?

Comment: @kelly Nothing special or exceptional. The instance is created, the method is called, the instance is no longer reachable and thus eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, So you mean to say its a one time activity, object is created with with no reference type. Object used and lost in memory because after that there is no reference is present to call back it again ? AM I correct ?

Comment: Yes,  That line of code just doesn't store the reference.  You _could_, that line just doesn't.

Comment: @kelly as others said, it is as simple as: `new T3()` creates a new instance of T3 and `.test()` calls a method on that instance. It is not saved into a reference since it's no longer needed, but you could do: `T3 t = new T3(); t.test();` and you'd have the exact same behavior. That said, what you showed: `T3 ob = new T3().test();` probably wouldn't compile since the method `test()` is probably `void` so you can't assign its return value into `T3 ob`

Answer (score 0):

Your expression parses as `(new T3()).test()`, not `new (T3().test())` as if it were destined to create a new object.  Therefore, as mentioned in comments, it creates a `T3` object, invokes the `test()` method on it, and discards the result.  (The `T3` object may or may not survive this processs, since it could publish pointers to itself in its constructor or in `test()`.)  It's no different from writing

```
static T3 findSomeT3() { /* could return a new one or an existing one */ }
public static void main(String[] args) {
  findSomeT3().test();
}
```

which also might or might not discard a `T3` object upon completion.

Note, by the way, that the name after `new` should not be considered a *constructor*; it's a class name.  A constructor is invoked to initialize it, of course, and the constructor is declared by treating the class's name as a function name, but it's still the class you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

> May I know what is happening with new T3().test(); ? Is it a new object ? If yest then why its not written as below?

`new T3()` creates and return an object. `test()` is calling a method on that.

> Or they have written in way because return type of test() method is void. Means no reference type can be created ? Am I correct?

`test()` returns `void`, but `new T3()` surely returns an object. You may have a reference to that like `T3 t3 = new T3().test();`. So you are just doing 2 tasks in 1 line.